# PHP function to know upload_max_filesize

Tags: php, upload, file-upload

I'v searching for a while in php.net and I don't find what I'm searching. I need a function to know the max_upload_filesize from a PHP function.

Here what I need: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [**ini_get()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) function:

```
<?php
$upload_max_size = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
```

Answer (score 16):

In addition to upload_max_filesize, watch out for post_max_size.
Whichever is the smaller will be enforced

Comment: That was very important information!  To increase upload file size limit adjusting two parameters was needed.  I struggled a while with WordPress wondering why the limit doesnẗ come up...

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [`ini_get`](http://php.net/ini_get) to get the config value.